# Completely Uninstall Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I want to completely uninstall Ubuntu 12.04.1. Because I'm really frustating while use this os.

Please help me how to uninstall 12.04.1 os. I have it's live cd.

Comment: Checkout this  post http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 3):

Before I provide you the directions to uninstall Ubuntu, I urge you to give it another chance. Whatever issues you're having are probably solvable. There's a very large Ubuntu community to help you out with any issues you may have.

That said, to completely uninstall Ubuntu you need to have a Windows CD available or access to the Windows Recovery Console (or just the CD for Windows Vista+).

If you installed Ubuntu from inside Windows (Wubi install), go to the very last section.

Boot the Windows CD.

XP:

- While the CD is loading it will tell you to "Press 'R' for System Recovery." Press 'R'.
- This will drop you to a black and white console.
- Select the Windows you want to do recovery on (usually there's only one)
- Enter your Administrator password, if any.
- Enter the command: `fixboot`
- Followed by: `fixmbr`
- Reboot

Vista+:

- Boot the CD
- Select your OS (usually only 1 avaialble)
- Tell it you want a command prompt
- Enter the command: `bootrec /fixboot`
- Enter the command: `bootrec /fixmbr`
- Reboot

In Windows:

- Go to the Control Panel
- Click on Administrative Tools (you may have to select "Classic View" on the upper right)
- Open "Computer Management"
- Select Disk Management
- Click the drive you installed Ubuntu on (usually C:)
- In the bottom of the Window, you'll see a blue section and probably a grey section.
- Right click the grey section and delete it.
- Then, right click the C: section and resize it to fill the disk.

Wubi Install (installed from inside Windows):

- Start up Windows.
- Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs (or Programs and Features)
- Find Ubuntu in the list and uninstall.
- OR run C:\ubuntu\Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe